# Factorizations of etale morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a finitely presented separated etale morphism, with $Y$ quasicompact and quasiseparated.

By Zariski’s main theorem, we can factor $f$ as $f= g \circ j$ with $j$ an open immersion and $g$ finite.

Can we choose $g$ to be flat?

Comment: No, you cannot typically choose $g$ to be flat.  Consider the morphism from an affine space of dimension $\geq 2$ to its quotient by a finite group of linear automorphisms that acts without pseudo-reflections.